# Interpreting the results of data analysis

Tags: plot

I'm looking for some help interpreting the results of my data for my graduate thesis. I am studying the effects of forest management on breeding songbirds. I have taken the data that has been collected over the past six years and have done an AICc analysis using multiple linear regression models with random and fixed effects. I have obtained AICc values for each model and have determined which models best describe the variation in the data, but I am having trouble getting those results into a presentable format using graphs, figures and, well, words. How do I show what the results of my analysis are in a concise manner, and are there ways to graph this type of analysis so that it looks good in a paper? I am open to using R to plot my results but I am still very new to the technology, and so I don't know what options there are in R, or what steps I would need to take to make the plots presentable.

Answer (score 1):

Using the ggplot2 library can produce some very publishable graphs directly from the outputs of LMMs and GLMMs from lme4::lmer and glmer objects but does have a learning curve. If you have both continuous and categorical predictors here is what I used for a current project. There are many settings there that look intimidating but it is a matter of searching over and over for a solution and finding the right piece of code that resolves your issue. If you have questions, let me know. I have annotated quite a bit to help.

I wanted to know whether the hedonic value of alcohol changed for rats reared in different environments (Environment) and with different levels of exposure to alcohol during adolescence (Condition).

I had 4 variables "c.conc" (Concentration mean centered to avoid issues with variance inflation due to multi-colinearity), "Sex", "Condition", "Environment". My concentration variable was within-subjects and thus, my repeated measure.

```
#Load in the required libraries

library("MASS")
library("lattice")
library("boot")
library("car")
library("emmeans")
library("lme4")
library("zoo")
library("tidyr")
library("multcomp")
library("foreign")
library("msm")
library("ggplot2")
library("effects")
library("lmerTest")

#Run the model and put the results into an object i called "Ehed" for Ethanol Hedonics

Ehed <-glmer(Total.Hedonic ~ c.conc*Sex*Condition*Environment
                 + (c.conc|RatID), data=mydetoh, family=poisson)
    summary(Ehed)

#Always check the normality of your residuals so you don't violate assumptions of residual distributions.
#In my case, they were very normal and the graph below will be saved as a .png to my current working directory to visually compare my residual distribution to a normal curve.
#to view your current working directory enter "getwd()" 

    #Residual Graph
      #make PNG file
      png("COBRE-2 Ehed Res Plot.png", width = 300, height = 300)
      #plot residual density function
      plot(density(residuals(Ehed)), 
           main="", xlab="", frame= FALSE)
      #Add normal distribution to the residual plot for comparison
      Ehed.res = residuals(Ehed)
      Ehed.m = mean(Ehed.res)
      Ehed.std = sqrt(var(Ehed.res))
      curve(dnorm(x, mean=Ehed.m, sd=Ehed.std), col="darkblue", lwd=2, add=TRUE, yaxt="n")
      #close the file
      dev.off()
```

Once you've run your models, you will need to do a few things to ensure you dont run into issues. Set up your Axis breaks based on your maximum values of your predicted variable. Rescale and un-center any continuous variables which should have been centered before the analysis to avoid issues with multi-colinearity (this is done in the same step as the next thing in this list). Pull your effects from your model object to effectively calculate your error ribbons for standard error of the mean (SEM).

```
#Predicted Graphs####

##Graph Setup####

##ETHANOL####
  #Axis and Break/Label Setup
    #Y Axis Breaks/Labels
      # generate hedonic (my predicted variable) Y axis break positions
      Ehed.ybreaks = c(0,50,100,150,200,250,300,350,400)
      # and Y labels; the ,"",100... omits the label for 50 but leaves the tick mark.
      # The length of the vectors must be the same so the ""s are necessary for this trick.
      Ehed.ylabels = as.character(c(0,"",100,"",200,"",300,"",400))

    #X Axis Breaks/Labels
      #assign X break positions for Concentration to object. My Concentration variable was 5%, 10%, 20%, etc... and appears below in the list (c())
      E.xbreaks = c(5,10,20,30,40)
      #assigns the values of the breaks to the X labels
      E.xlabels = as.character(E.xbreaks)

    ###Ethanol Hedonic Graph______________________________________________________
      #pull the effects from the GLMER model object & calculate confidence intervals for graphing
      Ehed.eff <- Effect(c("c.conc","Sex","Condition","Environment"),Ehed,
                         #se is std err and the level is the confidence level. .68 = actual std err for conf int. lower and upper.
                         se=list(level=.68),
                         #the xlevels command is used to increase the number of points calculated to smooth the error ribbons to look more curved (default = 5). I also center my concentration variable here to line up with the numbers that were analyzed as centered variables and remove this in the next step so everything is at their original values.
                         xlevels=list(c.conc=c(.05-mean.etoh.conc,
                                               .075-mean.etoh.conc,
                                               .10-mean.etoh.conc,
                                               .125-mean.etoh.conc,
                                               .15-mean.etoh.conc,
                                               .175-mean.etoh.conc,
                                               .20-mean.etoh.conc,
                                               .225-mean.etoh.conc,
                                               .25-mean.etoh.conc,
                                               .275-mean.etoh.conc,
                                               .30-mean.etoh.conc,
                                               .325-mean.etoh.conc,
                                               .35-mean.etoh.conc,
                                               .375-mean.etoh.conc,
                                               .40-mean.etoh.conc)))
#Writing Ehed.eff to a data frame to more easily use it with other functions later.
      Ehed.eff.df <-as.data.frame(Ehed.eff)
      #Converting back from the centering and rescaling.
      Ehed.eff.df$Concentration <- (Ehed.eff.df$c.conc+mean.etoh.conc)*100
      #Instead of trying to relabel these values in the ggplot2 object just recode them here and save some trouble
      Ehed.eff.df$Sex <-car::recode(Ehed.eff.df$Sex, "'F' = 'Female'; 'M' = 'Male'")
#The mydetoh is the original data set. If i want to show points for each individual I can use this data set layered on top of my other graph.
      mydetoh$Sex <-car::recode(mydetoh$Sex, "'F' = 'Female'; 'M' = 'Male'")

      #Check that everything looks right.
      View(Ehed.eff.df)
      View(mydetoh)

      #make a new file
      png("Fig Sample Ethanol Hedonic lines.png", width = 800, height = 600)
      #Start your plot and write it to an object for later reference. I chose Ehed.ggp because it is the Ehed model's ggplot. The fit variable below is generated when you pull the effects from the model. It is the predicted values.
#Because I am spliting the plot into two panes by sex, only Condition and Environment need to appear in my group, col (color), fill, and linetype arguments. The names must match the names of your variables from your model EXACTLY. The scale_color_manual etc... all align with these values. I used Hex colors, you can also just type "red" with the quotes instead.

      Ehed.ggp <-ggplot(Ehed.eff.df,
                        aes(Concentration,fit,
                            group=interaction(Condition,Environment),
                            col=interaction(Condition,Environment),
                            fill=interaction(Condition,Environment),
                            linetype=interaction(Condition,Environment),
                            shape=interaction(Condition,Environment)))+
        #adds each individual's points to the data. Leave this commented out if you dont need to do that.
        #geom_point(data=mydetoh,aes(x=Concentration, y=Total.Hedonic),stroke=1.5,size=4,alpha=0.60)+
        geom_smooth(data=Ehed.eff.df, se=FALSE, method="glm", method.args = list(family = "poisson"),size=1.5)+
        ## colour=NA suppresses edges of the ribbon
        geom_ribbon(data=Ehed.eff.df,colour=NA,alpha=0.25,
                    aes(ymin=lower,ymax=upper))+
        #labs(tag="A.")+  #If you do not need a panel tag (e.g. A., B., C. etc...) for a graph that will become part of a larger plot, comment this command out
        scale_color_manual("",values=c("#0000ff", "#7d7dff","#ff0000","#ff7d7d","#000000","#808080"), labels=c('EC+ETOH','EC+SAL','IC+ETOH','IC+SAL','SC+ETOH','SC+SAL'))+
        scale_fill_manual("",values=c("#0000ff", "#7d7dff","#ff0000","#ff7d7d","#000000","#808080"), labels=c('EC+ETOH','EC+SAL','IC+ETOH','IC+SAL','SC+ETOH','SC+SAL'))+
        scale_linetype_manual("",values=c("solid","twodash","solid","twodash","solid","twodash"), labels=c('EC+ETOH','EC+SAL','IC+ETOH','IC+SAL','SC+ETOH','SC+SAL'))+
        scale_shape_manual("",values=c(15,0,16,1,17,2), labels=c('EC+ETOH','EC+SAL','IC+ETOH','IC+SAL','SC+ETOH','SC+SAL'))+
        scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0), limits = c(0,42), breaks=E.xbreaks, labels=E.xlabels)+
        scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0), limits = c(0,410), breaks=Ehed.ybreaks, labels=Ehed.ylabels)+
        theme_classic()+
        theme(strip.background = element_rect(colour="white"),
              strip.text.x = element_text(size=18,face="bold"),
              panel.spacing = unit(1,"cm"),
              axis.title = element_text(size=22),
              axis.text = element_text(size=21,color="black",face="bold"),
              axis.line = element_line(size=1.3),
              axis.ticks = element_line(size=1.3, color="black"),
              axis.ticks.length = unit(0.2, "cm"),
              axis.title.y = element_text(margin = margin(t = 0, r = 18, b = 0, l = 0)),
              axis.title.x = element_text(margin = margin(t = 13, r = 0, b = 0, l = 0)),
              legend.title = element_blank(),
              legend.text = element_text(size=18, face="bold"),
              legend.justification = "top",
              legend.key.size = unit(1, "cm"),
              #legend.position = c(0.75, .85),
              #plot.tag = element_text(size=36, face="bold"),
              plot.tag.position = c(0.05, 0.95))+
        facet_grid(. ~ Sex)+
        xlab("Ethanol % (v/v)")+
        ylab("Hedonic Responses (+/-SEM)")

      Ehed.ggp

      #close the file
      dev.off()
```

Unfortunately I do not have time to explain more right now. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: This helps a lot. Thank you. If I need more help, I will respond to this post.

Comment: So, all of my models are right - tailed, which means they are violating the assumptions of the lmer function that I used for them. Is there a way to correct this? Is there something else I need to do to make it correct?